# Halakha and practicality of a halachic state

Tags: halacha, politics-government, free-will-bechira, state-of-israel, public-policy

Is there a practical  issue with trying to govern a state in a theocracy  by Halakha without divine revelation? Even believing it’s okay to have a Jewish state exist before moshiach, would it still be considered wrong due to the practical debates in halakha. Such as how a state could coordinate kosher production, modesty, Shabbat and Yom Tov observance, fasting during certain times, prayer, bioethics, charity etc.? Would it depend on the type of Halakha being enforced?

Comment: I've heard a Rabbi say that a big issue with state-enforced halacha is it goes against the principle of free will. Hashem wants our hearts, and wants us to serve Him freely, and imposing it by force defeats His purpose.

Comment: I’m asking the question with the assumption that even if it is allowed to have a Jewish state before messiah whether actual Halacha itself would still be impossible to enforce @Shmuel and what types of Halacha are acceptable to enforce via state force. From a variety of potential issues like disagreements in Halacha and free will etc.

Comment: @RabbiKaii who? where? any source for this position in (classic) Jewish souces? Doesn't Torah say Shoftim vShotrim ttein lcha?

Comment: The answer is of course it's a practical challenge for the reasons you mentioned and more. Does that mean it's forbidden to try?

Comment: It is related that the Brisker Rav told that one of the problems of that is that the Arabs would not accept it (Peninei Rabbeinu HaGriz, p. 148). Also, we have no King that enforces halacha etc...

Comment: @RabbiKaii I don't think we're discussing enforcing every halacha on every person, but having a legal system that is based on halacha rather than secular law.

Comment: Yeah just to clarify I’m not talking about a state with officers that patrol people’s houses to make sure they don’t text on Shabbat, I mean a state that generally prohibits electricity production on Shabbat, regulates religious marriage and divorce without civil unions, sanctions Mikvaot and eruvin construction etc. @RabbiKaii

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi Rambam says the only ones who can enforce halacha is the beis din (with shotrim etc) that only comes when there is a Sanhedrin. We beat a husband to _wanting_ to give a _get_, etc.

Comment: @RabbiKaii and the Rambam also has thoughts on how to re-establish semikhah so that said Sanhedrin can establish shofetim weshotrim... I'm not understanding how your answer resolves the contradiction NaftaliTzvi points out

Comment: @Deuteronomy very interesting, I guess another attempt at an explanation is, shofetim and shotrim _are_ free will powered mitzvot in and of themselves.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Perhaps by those that initially enable those institutions to become manifest, but not those that are later subject to it... leaving us back at the beginning again. Would you mind sharing which rabbi said that, and in what context?

Comment: @Deuteronomy the context was enforcing halacha in Eretz Yisrael by government, and wasn't a rigorous halachic statement. I appreciate the hashkafa behind it though, and have made an attempt to try to defend it, but any further defense would be fun, but probably taking it too seriously. Rabbi Manis Friedman btw

Comment: @RabbiKaii Got it, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Deuteronomy it is interesting how the pasuk states "titen _lecha_" (Devarim 16:18). Quite apt.

Comment: @RabbiKaii, my recollection is that what's learned out is that the miswa applies in E"Y not the diaspora, but that's a cute additional defense.. I'm sure R. Manis Friedman would be pleased.

Comment: @Deuteronomy some interpret in ways that are even more pleasing to him, I'd imagine, e.g. Kli Yakar: https://www.sefaria.org/Kli_Yakar_on_Deuteronomy.16.18.2?lang=bi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this directly answers the question (since I'm not clear on what the question is asking), but I find it remarkable that both Rabbi Shmuel Yaakov Weinberg and Rabbi Meir Kahane (debate with Prof. Allen Dershowiz), two quiet different figures, expressed the same view regarding a Halachic State. "G-d forbid to do anything that would lead to civil war."

Comment: The OP was asking for "practical debates".